# CSS class styles affecting HTML elements outside of class definition

Tags: html, css

Style properties defined under one class affects the properties of another element with a different class definition.

Specifically the styles for the th and td from the Movement table are overwriting the ones defined  in the Characteristics table. Inspecting the styles within Chrome it clearly shows that the Movement styles are trumping the Characteristic settings.

A working example of the code is below. It can run at this link from [w3chools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild).

I've tried numerous variations and have been unable to correct it. Checked here and other sites for solutions but to no avail.

I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```css
.grid-container-0 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 5px auto;
  width: 200mm;
  border: solid black thin;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-container-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.grid-container-5 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  border: none;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.title {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

div.characteristics {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.characteristics th,
td {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.characteristics th:last-of-type,
td:last-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}

.characteristics tr:last-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.movement {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.movement th,
td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-0">
    <div class="grid-item characteristics">
      <div class="grid-container-2">
        <div class="grid-item characteristics-1 title">CHARACTERISTICS</div>
        <div class="grid-item characteristics-2">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Val</th>
              <th>Char</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Roll</th>
              <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>STR</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>11-</td>
              <td>HTH Damage 2d6 END [1]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>DEX</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>11-</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>CON</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>11-</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>INT</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>11-</td>
              <td>PER Roll 11-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>EGO</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>11-</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>PRE</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>11-</td>
              <td>PRE Attack: 2d6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>OCV</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>DCV</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>OMCV</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>DMCV</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>SPD</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Phases: 6, 12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>PD</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>2 PD (0 rPD)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>ED</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>2 ED (0 rED)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>REC</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>END</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>BODY</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>STUN</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>Total Characteristic Points</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item movement">
      <div class="grid-container-5">
        <div class="grid-item movement-1 title">MOVEMENT</div>
        <div class="grid-item movement-2">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Run</td>
              <td>12m[24m NC]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Swim</td>
              <td>4m[8m NC]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>H. Leap</td>
              <td>4m</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>V. Leap</td>
              <td>2m</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see that to be the case. Inspecting a `th` in `characteristics-2 > table` shows only styles for that class. Do I misunderstand? Might help if you modified the snippet above to demonstrate with disparate colors or something.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `.characteristics th, td` in your CSS, you're apparently expecting that to apply to `.characteristics th` and `.characteristics td` elements.

However, that isn't what it means: it actually applies to `.characteristics th` elements and *all* `td` elements. So that's why you're seeing styles intended for one class in places they shouldn't be.

Here's an example:

```css
.red i, b {color:red}
.blue i, b {color:blue}
```

```html
<div class="red">1 <i>2</i> <b>3</b></div>
<div class="blue">4 <i>5</i> <b>6</b></div>
```

You'd expect 2 and 3 to be red, and 5 and 6 to be blue, but that doesn't actually happen: both the `color:red` and `color:blue` rules apply to *all* `b` elements, so they'll end up the same color as each other (in this case, blue).

To fix this, `.characteristics th, td` has to be written as `.characteristics th, .characteristics td` (and likewise with other places where you've used commas).

Comment: Thank you! Everything is displaying correctly now. By consolidating the CSS I shot myself in the foot.